# reboot doesn't reboot

Tags: 12.04, server, reboot

I've used `reboot` for quite a few years to reboot Ubuntu Server, but now the command just puts Ubuntu into some low level, unresponsive state and I have to use the reset button to reboot. I don't have a monitor connected to the server. How can I troubleshoot this?

It began after the last HWE update, where at first it was spurious, but now it's every time I try to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

On my old Dell I had to use

```
reboot=acpi
```

[kernel paramenter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter), hinted from [here](http://linux.koolsolutions.com/2009/08/04/howto-fix-linux-hangfreeze-during-reboots-and-restarts/). Maybe you need a couple of experiments --- my old Dell did not restart every other reboot (!) without the kernel parameter. BIOS mysteries...

Comment: The problem is that it used to reboot every single time. I've been using this motherboard for over four years.

Comment: Could be a regression introduced by the new kernel in the HWE update...

Comment: What do you mean? The current Ubuntu was installed in May/June with the 12.04 ISO.

Comment: The HWE update will normally install a newer kernel --- it will enable newer drivers and so on, but it can (although it's quite rare) introduce bugs and regressions.